# Select first monitor Api google

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I'm using the RecordRTC library for a project. I need to set it to record the first screen in full screen and to not show this dialog:

[image]

In the Google API it mentions the attribute `deviceId` and I need to know which one to my monitor by default. This is my code:

```js
function invokeGetDisplayMedia(success, error) {
  if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
    var displaymediastreamconstraints = {
      video: {
        "aspectRatio": 1.7777777777777777,
        "deviceId": "screen:0:0",
        "frameRate": 30,
        "height": 1080,
        "resizeMode": "crop-and-scale",
        "width": 1920,
        displaySurface: 'monitor',
        logicalSurface: true,
        "frameRate": 30,
        cursor: 'always',
      }
    };

    displaymediastreamconstraints = {
      "aspectRatio": 1.7777777777777777,
      "deviceId": "screen:0:0",
      "frameRate": 30,
      "height": 1080,
      "resizeMode": "crop-and-scale",
      "width": 1920,
      "cursor": "always",
      "displaySurface": "monitor",
      "logicalSurface": true,
      video: true,
    };
    
    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
  } else {
    navigator.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. User interaction is required to confirm the monitor choice when recording starts

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, meybe that is about of the limitations of chorme,right? , I did read  a lot of this topic in:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture#Options_and_constraints